# Why android notification text is not displayed?

Tags: android

I have written following code for notification, I can able to see notification and title of the notification but text is not visible. i tried many times with static value but still not getting what's problem. Please help me, thanks in advance.

```
private void messagenotification(String msg, String nextid) {


    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("id", nextid  ).apply();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.blue)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.blue))
            .setContentTitle("Chat")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);



    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that you forgot `.setContentText("Example")` on your notificationBuilder

Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContentText(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: Thanks for your reply, let me check.